# Get link from Oracle APEX 5 Chart-item on page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

Really need help with next:

```
select 
    'f?p=&APP_ID.:161:'||:app_session||'::::P161_FORM_TYPE_ID,P161_LAYERS_THICKNESS,P161_TASK_ID_NUMBER:'||q.FORM_TYPE_ID||','||n.LAYER_THICKNESS||','||p.TASK_ID_NUMBER||' ' link,
```

I need get this link (URL) from "char-item" on page in jQuery. But I do not see and do not understand how I can get it?

Comment: Please provide more information about what is your goal, what are you doing and what is your problem. Now you have only incomplete query.

Comment: If you want to ask in Russian, ask [here](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) or [there](http://www.sql.ru/forum/oracle-apex)

Comment: There is SELECT in it there is UNION ALL (as shown above).Link is formed differently, refers to the different pages.
1) `SELECT ... 'f p = & APP_ID:?. 161:' ... link UNION ALL`
2) `SELECT. .. 'f p = & APP_ID:?. 160:' ... link `
I need the link on the page. 
What for? 
To set different colors of items if they refer to page 160 and 161.

Comment: Can I get the link from item in matrix, to the page 160 or 160 via Jquery?